# Porting to Lua 5.2, LUA_GLOBALSINDEX trouble

Tags: lua, lua-5.2

In the code example: http://lua-users.org/wiki/SimplerCppBinding

There is the code:

```
lua_pushstring(L, T::className);
lua_pushvalue(L, methods);
lua_settable(L, LUA_GLOBALSINDEX);  //<--- LUA_GLOBALSINDEX removed in Lua 5.2

lua_pushliteral(L, "__metatable");
lua_pushvalue(L, methods);
lua_settable(L, metatable);
```

In Lua 5.2, LUA_GLOBALSINDEX no longer exists. Instead, it has lua_setglobal() and lua_getglobal().

---

Am I correct in thinking that:

```
lua_pushvalue(L, methods);
lua_setglobal(L, T::className);
```

...is the correct replacement for:

```
lua_pushstring(L, T::className);
lua_pushvalue(L, methods);
lua_settable(L, LUA_GLOBALSINDEX);
```

I'm too new to Lua to be sure, I haven't used it for 8 months. Looking at the documentation, I'm *thinking* this is correct, but would like verification.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of `lua_settable(L,LUA_GLOBALSINDEX);` use `lua_setglobal(L,T::className);`. That works in both Lua 5.1 and 5.2.

Comment: Yes, but am I using lua_setglobal() correctly?
lua_pushvalue(L, methods);
lua_setglobal(L, T::className);

Comment: @ComServant, if `T::className` is a `char*`, then yes. Is it not working?